# How to select only the first input with my css?

Tags: css

Hi can you please help with some css,
I have this code

```
<div>
  <div>
     <input class="test"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
     <input class="test"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
     <input class="test"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change some properties only in my first input, can somebody help me solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: I gave the answer. Did you mean that?

Comment: yes but i cant accept your answer because i dont have the reputation to do that, ty <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can use these css rules:

```
div:nth-child(1) div input.test {
  color: green;
}
```

or

```
div:first-of-type div input.test {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)